# WSO2 ESB-4.8.1 connecting to WSO2-5.0.0 IS and UserInformationRecoveryService?wsdl

Tags: rest, soap, wsdl, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am trying to connect WSO2 Identity Server to the WSO2 ESB. I have installed both products to my local computer and have configured them to run simultaneously. WSO2-IS has an offset of 1 and I set hostnameverifier to AllowAll. Given that both are on my local machine, I did not see the need to adjust or set anything in the Keystore. In WSO2-IS I have exposed the admin-wsdl's.

What I am trying to do is create an endpoint wsdl that points to
https://localhost:9444/services/UserInformationRecoveryService?wsdl (which is in the WSO2-IS).

In the admin console, I add the endpoint with the variables
 1. The Name is UserInformationRecoveryService
 2. The URI is https://localhost:9444/services/UserInformationRecoveryService?wsdl
 3. The Service is UserInformationRecoveryService
 4. The port is 9444 (which is the offset from 9443)

When I test this service, it says it is valid. When I add it, it disappears and I get the errors:

> [2015-01-16 17:59:20,923] ERROR - WSDL11EndpointBuilder Couldn't retrieve endpoint information from the WSDL.
>   [2015-01-16 17:59:20,924] ERROR - WSDLEndpointFactory Couldn't create endpoint from the given WSDL URI : Couldn't retrieve endpoint information from the WSDL.
>   org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Couldn't retrieve endpoint information from the WSDL.
>       at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.endpoints.utils.WSDL11EndpointBuilder.handleException(WSDL11EndpointBuilder.java:199)
>   ... (I removed many of the other at's)

I also tried adding it as a wsdl proxy, but receive the error

> Couldn't create endpoint from the given WSDL URI : Couldn't retrieve endpoint information from the WSDL.

and the errors:

> [2015-01-16 18:06:49,890] ERROR - ProxyServiceAdminClient Couldn't create endpoint from the given WSDL URI : Couldn't retrieve endpoint information from the WSDL.
>   org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.stub.ProxyServiceAdminProxyAdminException: Couldn't create endpoint from the given WSDL URI : Couldn't retrieve endpoint information from the WSDL.
>       at org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.ui.client.ProxyServiceAdminClient.addProxy(ProxyServiceAdminClient.java:105)
>       at org.apache.jsp.proxyservices.template_005fwsdl_002dbased_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.proxyservices.template_005fwsdl_002dbased_jsp:343)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)

I am relatively new to the WSO2 suite, and have been unable to find many discussions on these two products working together.

From what I have read, WSO2-IS uses SOAP. The client that we are developing will be using REST. The ESB is to connect the client to WSO2-IS and convert SOAP-TO-REST.

My question is
    1. Why do I receive these errors?
    2. What is the best practice to connect the two services.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Enable  option in carbon.xml and try your wsdl  link in a browser and see whether you can access it or not.(All admin services's wsdls are hided)  Later try to create proxy.

Comment: I have enabled the wsdl in carbon.xml and tested it in a browser. It does appear in the browser, but does not work when I try to create a wsdl endpoint or a proxy. The errors I listed above appear when trying to create the endpoint/proxy.

Would running both WSO2 ESB and WSO2 IS on the same machine affect this? I had one small, unrepeatable, success when trying to connect ESB and IS through endpoint on separate machines.

Comment: Can you provide your proxy configuration/endpoint configuration.? If it is a WSDL proxy you should give wsdl port as port and service as mentioned in wsdl.

Comment: I figured that out. Thank you for the aid. I was putting the port in wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After more reading, I found that I was using the wrong port name. I was assuming the port was 9444, but having reread the wsdl again, I found that the ports were called

> wsdl:port name="UserInformationRecoveryServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint"
>       wsdl:port name="UserInformationRecoveryServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint"
>       wsdl:port name="UserInformationRecoveryServiceHttpsEndpoint"